# Have bootstrap button not change on click?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootstrap and I'm trying to make a set of buttons that *only* execute an action when clicked, and nothing else (e.g. not change the color of the button fill, not change the outline color, just have it stay the same like the navbar buttons [here.](https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/YqLyXB/))

This is what I have so far:

```
.btn-default {
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #F5C173;
  background-color: #8F390D;
  border-color: #8F390D;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: #8F390D;
  border-color: #8F390D;
  color: #9F590D;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

And here's where I declare the buttons:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-default" style="float: right">about</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-default" style="float: right">portfolio</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn navbar-btn btn-default" style="float: right">contact</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Basically, I want the hover effect to persist regardless if the button is clicked or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding the rules to focus as well: `.btn-default:hover, .btn-default:focus {`

Comment: thanks, didn't know that focus existed @RichardHowell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add important behind everything you want to stay the same, like this:

```
.btn-default {
  font-family: Monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #F5C173!important;
  background-color: #8F390D!important;
  border-color: #8F390D!important;
  border-radius: 0px;
  box-shadow: none!important;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: #8F390D!important;
  border-color: #8F390D!important;
  color: #9F590D!important;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)!important;
}
```